# 1 row friendship extra option

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an app that manage mutual friendship in one single row per relation.

This is my query

```
SELECT users.id, users.username, users.name, avatar.media_url  FROM users
  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM media ORDER BY media.id DESC ) avatar ON (avatar.media_author = users.id AND avatar.media_type = 'avatar') 
  WHERE users.id IN(
   (SELECT user_from FROM friends WHERE user_to = 53 AND status = 1 )
   UNION
   (SELECT user_to FROM friends WHERE user_from = 53  AND status = 1)
                    )
GROUP BY users.id
```

And this is my table

```
CREATE TABLE `friends` (
  `user_from` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `user_to` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0 pending | 1 accepted | 2 declined | 3 blocked',
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `temp_from_to` int(1) DEFAULT '2',
  `temp_to_from` int(11) DEFAULT '2',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_from`,`user_to`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

As you said I've added two new field ( temp_from_to - temp_to_from ) where I want to save a value (1, 2 or 3). This value may be different based on relationship direction, for example:

user_1 have a relation with user_2, for the first user the relation has a value of 1, for the second the value of 3. How I can store that data and retrieve it to make sure that the relationship value tha i get and set is based on my logged-in user?

In a few word: I want be sure to have value of temp_from_to in row where the selected user is in user_from field, and temp_to_from in row where the selected user is in user_to field.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: What are u trying to achieve with this? You can try: `WHERE temp_from_to IN (SELECT temp_from_to FROM friends WHERE user_from = :ïd )` where ':id' is your logged in ID

Comment: With actual query I select all friend (in user_from I have the id of the users that requested the relation and in user_to the id of the user that accepted the relation), so in the first case I need to select the temp_from_to and in the second the temp_to_from, this value represent the value of the relationship for every single user

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a lot easier by simplifying your table structure.
If you want a table that keeps friends of users then you could do this:

```
 CREATE TABLE `friends` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `friend_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0 pending | 1 accepted | 2 declined | 3 blocked',
  `strength` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '0 weak| 1 normal| 2 strong|',
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`friend_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

The `user_id` is the ID of the user that requested the friendship and the `friend_id` is the ID of the user that got the friendrequest.

**Get friends of logged in user:**
`SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (user_id = :loggedinID OR friend_id = :loggedinID) AND status = 1`

**Get friendrequests of logged in user:**
`SELECT * FROM friends WHERE friend_id = :loggedinID AND status = 0`

**Get blocked users of logged in user:**
`SELECT * FROM friends WHERE friend_id = :loggedinID AND status = 3`

**Get declined friendrequests of logged in user:**
`SELECT * FROM friends WHERE friend_id = :loggedinID AND status = 2`

Comment: Hi, tnx, the problem with your solution are two:
- I need to have a join for user media
- I need to get also the relationship value therefore another join in friends table (and here the problem to select only the correct relatioship value)

Comment: So you need to collect user info, user media and the user friends?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that user friends have a relationship value (like a rating) that can be different for every user involved in the relationship

Comment: how do you mean 'every user involved in the relationship ?'

Comment: a user is befriend with another user and thats it right? what are your goals with adding a relationship value?

Comment: I can choose that I have a really good (or only a good or a cold) relationship with one user this change the way in which I can interact with this user. The problem is that: I feel that I have a relation value of 3 with one user but the feel that have relation of value of 1 with me...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198483/discussion-between-jbadminton-and-red).